# HTML's data attribute undefined in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm using the following code to access an HTML data attribute:

**HTML**

```
<p class="add-favorites-to-list">
  <a href="#" data-baskettype="order"><img src="/style/icons/cart_add.png"> Test1</a>
  <a href="#" data-baskettype="quote"><img src="/style/icons/calculator_add.png"> Test2</a>
</p>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-favorites-to-list').show();
  $('.add-favorites-to-list a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('baskettype'));
    return false;
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.add-favorites-to-list { display: none; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mR8gK/1/

Which works fine on jsFiddle, however it doesn't work in my site (with the same code and the same browser). I get an `undefined` in the `alert()`.

I've checked if jQuery finds the element and it does, because: `console.log($(this).html());` shows the contents of the element.

Is there any (obvious) reason why that code wouldn't work in my site but does work on jsFiddle?

Comment: I'd guess it might be something to do with the doctype

Comment: @adam: At the top of my document I've got: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Which should be HTML5 if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you running? Because if you drop it below `1.4.4` it comes back as undefined.

Comment: Ha! Phil: you rock!!! It is an old project I'm working on. And forgot it was still using 1.4.2. Time for an upgrade.

Comment: Yay, glad I was able to help!